# About the proof of finite subaddivity for separated sets (Lebesgue outer measure)

Tags: measure-theory, lebesgue-measure

The Lebesgue outer measure for $E\cup F\subset \mathbb{R}^d$ is defined as$$m^*(E\cup F)=\inf_{\cup_{n=1}^\infty B_n\supset (E\cup F), B_n\text{ boxes}}\sum_{n=1}^\infty|B_n|$$

in Terence Tao's measure theory [book](https://terrytao.files.wordpress.com/2012/12/gsm-126-tao5-measure-book.pdf), page 23. In the proof for finite subadditivity for separated sets he lets $\varepsilon > 0$, and asserts that we can cover $E\cup F$ by a countable family of boxes $B_1, B_2, \cdots$ such that

$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty|B_n|\leq m^*(E\cup F)+\varepsilon$$

I don't see why this should be true for any $\varepsilon > 0$; by the definition we obviously have

$$m^*(E\cup F)\leq\sum_{n=1}^\infty|B_n|$$

because we were taking the infimum of that sum in the definition of outer measure. Why does adding any $\varepsilon > 0$ result in the reverse inequality in this step of the proof?

Comment: This is a property of the infimum.  Since the outer measure is defined as the infimum over all suitable countable unions of boxes, you are guaranteed to always have a union of boxes whose sum of measures is within $\epsilon$ of the outer measure.

Comment: Yeah, I think I got it now. For every $\varepsilon > 0$ we pick we can get a smaller and smaller cover that works for that value. I should do some revision exercises in analysis, I guess :/